# using pattern: specific action on exception

Tags: c#, idisposable

I'm trying to refresh my memory on C# and `using` pattern.
Is there a possibility to have some control flow be executed automatically on exception?

For instance:

```
class Test : IDisposable
{
     public void Dispose()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("ok");
     }

     public void XX()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("KO");
     }
}

using (new Test()) 
{
}
// prints "ok"


using (new Test())
{
    throw new Exception();
}
// this would print "KO"
```

Is there a way to achieve this effect in C# ?
Example of use case would be : a database system where I want to commit result on correct execution, but rollback on exception

For example, currently to handle transaction commits/rollback, it's possible to do this :

```
using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    try 
    {
        // DO WORK
        tran.Commit();
    } catch {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

But this means that clients of "tran" object have to correctly write the try/catch code. I'm looking for a way to provide the same functionality out of the box, so that users just have to write the "DO WORK" code (and the "using") and not have to write the "using" and the try/catch code

Comment: Do you understand why your current code would print "ok" twice?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes I understand why. What I'm trying to find is if there is an elegant way to do the behavior I wrote without requiring boilerplate

Comment: Dispose runs when you leave the scope. Doesn't matter _how_ that happens. Is there something more advanced that a try/catch can't solve?

Comment: @gunr2171 the "pattern" I'm looking for would be that the Test class handles the try/catch logic, and not the user of the Test class

Comment: @lezebulon Why can't you create one method that accepts an `Action` delegate and wrap that inside the try/catch you have in your example? The user would then provide the `DoWork` via `Action` delegate and you would handle the try/catch for them.

Comment: I can, but it's just less clear to read in terms of syntax / control flow.

Comment: @lezebulon How is that less clear? Please explain. You could also handle the `using` statement for the user as well.

Comment: C# does not provide a custom syntax for that. You have to do manual try/catch.

Comment: _"or example, currently to handle transaction commits/rollback, it's possible to do this :"_ - AFAIK there is no need to write inner try-catch block, transaction will be automatically rolled back unless you commit it inside the using block.

Comment: @GuruStron that depends on the (transaction) implemention.

Comment: "But this means that clients of "tran" object have to correctly write the try/catch code." That's actually not true. SqlTransaction will rollback for you if you don't explicitly commit. It just doesn't have access to the exception information.

Comment: @freakish it is a standard practice, at least for `SqlTransaction` (see for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127830/why-use-a-using-statement-with-a-sqltransaction)), but in general - yes.

Comment: ok, maybe the "rollback" catch part is no needed. But it still means that users in that case have to manually (remember to) call commit() as the last statement. My question is how to avoid this : have commit() be called at the end of regular control flow, and rollback() (or nothing) in case of exception unwind

Comment: @lezebulon as I said earlier: C# does not provide a syntax for that. You have to manually try/catch. Maybe inconvenient, but it is what it is.

Comment: @lezebulon it is not possible. The transaction approach is the [way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301548/2501279)

Answer (score 1):

What you want isn't 100% achievable. `IDisposable` is not designed to handle exceptions. It's designed to free up a resource when that resource goes out of scope.

[`SqlTransaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) does something similar. You create a `using` scoped variable, and if you don't explicitly commit the transaction, it will rollback the transaction.

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
   // ...
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

You could emulate something like this, and require the user to say if the body of the `using` block was successful or not.

```
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    private bool Successful { get; private set; } = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Successful)
            // ...
        else
            // ...
    }

    public void Success() => Successful = true;
}
```

```
using (var test = new Test())
{
    // ...
    test.Success();
}
```

Just note, you cannot get the exception information from `Dispose`. You also can't be sure if an exception was thrown or the user forgot to call `.Success()` when `Successful` is false.

---

Instead, you really need to do error handling *inside* the using scope.

Comment: Ok I see
Indeed your alternate version is something I had in mind, but in any case it doesnt change much whether the user has to call either Success() or Commit() at the end